# Why can't I use @$ prefix before strings?

Tags: c#, string, prefix, string-interpolation

All these string prefixes are legal to use in C#:

```
  "text"
 @"text"
 $"text"
$@"text"
```

Why isn't this?

```
@$"text"
```

One would have thought that the order of these operators doesn't matter, because they have no other meaning in C# but to prefix strings. I cannot think of a situation when this inverted double prefix would not compile. Is the order enforced only for aesthetic purposes?

Comment: I don't think they are commutative: `$@""` means interpolate in a verbatim string, that makes sense. But what would you have `@$""` do?  Take the string verbatim _after_ interpolation  ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Interpolated verbatim strings were not allowed before C# version 8, for no other reason than they weren't implemented. However, this is now possible, so both of these lines will work:

```
var string1 = $@"text";
var string2 = @$"text";
```

Answer (score 7):

These prefixes aren't operators. They are only interpreted by the compiler. While it understands `$@` it doesn't understand `@$`. Why? Because Microsoft's compiler team decided so.

However, support for the latter is [planned for C# 8.0](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/1630)

Answer (score 1):

According to [msDocs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated)

> A verbatim interpolated string starts with the `$` character followed by
>   the `@` character.
>
> The $ token must appear before the @ token in a verbatim interpolated
>   string.

Perhaps this is the way they designed to be understandable by the current version of c# compiler.